# React-native iOS app not running on terminal and Xcode also

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, build-error

Hello I'm Beginner in React Native,
I've installed everything did they said.

Now I've created application using below command 
`react-native init TempApp`

Application is created successfully

Now I try to run application using below command 
`npx react-native run-ios`

I got below error

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/encora/Documents/Paresh\ Workspace/React\ Native\ Projects/TempApp/ios/Pods/YogaKit/YogaKit/Source/YGLayoutExtensions.swift

CompileC /Users/encora/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TempApp-fnxepatpnxxjncbfdflpymtfxxag/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SysUio.o /Users/encora/Documents/Paresh\ Workspace/React\ Native\ Projects/TempApp/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/SysUio.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(2 failures)

Even I try to run application from Xcode also, but I still get error in Xcode also.

Can anyone help me please how to run first react application on Mac

Answer (score 0):

Try this -
Close the  Xcode,delete node_modules folder and then run commands in project directory

```
npm install / yarn install
cd ios && pod install --repo-update
npx react-native run-ios
```

Option 3 is optional either run project from terminal or from Xcode

Comment: Above command still not work for me.

Comment: Delete the content of Derived data folder present at Users/encora/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and then check

Comment: solution for the issues  https://stackoverflow.com/a/72247277/11104759